# Firebase hosting not showing up app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am new to firebase, and I try to deploy my app to firebase. I have followed all the steps. But, for some reason is not showing up my app. I am getting the welcome modal instead of my web app. 
Here are the images: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which file is your main web app page in? Index.html?

Comment: Yes. its in  public directory

Comment: I'm pretty sure index.html is generally in public folder... did view folder appear when you did an initialize with firebase CLI? Can you please check public folder for index.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have public folder, where everything is in there.

Comment: For your URL can you try again with '/index.html' appended to the end?

Comment: it brings up to the welcome modal shown in my question

Comment: At the top level of your firebase directory can you please check firebase.json file and see what the 'destination' property is set to ?

Comment: yes its next to the public folder

Comment: it is set: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}

Comment: nothing else, in the file

Comment: Can you please try changing to : 
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}  and then re-deploy

Comment: is the source going to be Astricts? also, after should I firebase deploy?

Comment: Yes try to deploy

Comment: nothing shows up. same welcome modal. :/

Comment: Weird.. I guess my final suggestion is please double check public/index.html and make sure that it's your code and not the modal you're seeing

Comment: ok. thank you. If I need further question, I will ping you

Comment: ok, now it worked. But It does NOT go to my other routes

Comment: How did it start working? As in it doesn't go to your other web pages? Are they in public as well? Maybe it takes time to upload on hosting.. It could be a caching thing also..Are you using chrome? Try opening incognito.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. yes and it still doesnt work with incognito

Comment: its in the public folder, with bunch of folders in it. is thats why?

Comment: It has to be directly in the public folder as index.html... not within other folders

Comment: ok. give me a second let me put it all as in files

Comment: how about for node modules? Should I put that outside the folder?

Comment: Now, it upload 2 files.

Comment: How did you set this up in the first place? I think you should let firebase CLI do the work for you.  Maybe try doing an `firebase init` in your command line and set it up again?

Comment: I tried it. still the routes/pages dont work.

Comment: does `firebase serve` work on localhost?

Comment: no, shows the same thing

Comment: does it matter, if my app is a nodejs app. Maybe, firebase is not compatible with NodeJS?

Comment: By the way, it worked. What I did is...  I put everything in public  folder, and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: if you provide index.html in public folder it should be shown here.

Answer (score 33):

The step to deploy are as following

**STEP 1:**

```
ng build --prod
```

**STEP 2:**

```
firebase init

    *Are you ready to proceed?* Yes

    *What do you want to use as your public directory?* dist/{your-application-name}

    *Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?(y/N)* Yes

    *File dist/{your-application-name}/index.html already exists. Overwrite?(y/N)* No
```

**STEP 3:**

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

And if still you are getting the same page just press 'CTRL + F5' it will clean the cached.

Comment: firebase deploy --only hosting
this works for me, but what it means only hosting?

Comment: it will just deploy new hosting configuration, not other configurations. if we remove `--only hosting` firebase will deploy all configurations(functions, hosting..).

Comment: It didnt work for me. I even created a fresh project on firebase just to make sure no settings from the previous deployments were retained.

Answer (score 17):

It's because the `index.html` has modified itself when you selected `"Y"` while **initializing** the **firebase**. It has basically replaced your own index file to this one. Check and replace the index file and next time, do not overwrite index.html file. It would work.

Comment: Actually, if you overwrote the index file as before. First, build project after that firebase init

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem. In my case the issue was not with firebase. Just clearing the cache was the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Firebase hosting not showing up app?

There might be two reasons for this problem

1st step:

Make sure your public folder (define in your firebase.json) 'dist' containing the index.html hasn't been modified by firebase init command, if yes replace it with your original project index.html

for reference  (dist is standard but your may different)

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist"    
  }
}
```

2nd step:

Make sure to configure your base href in project's index.html

as

```
< base href="https://["YOUR FIREBASE PROJECT NAME"].firebaseapp.com/">
```

and other bundle files as

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="https://["YOUR FIREBASE PROJECT NAME"].firebaseapp.com/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script>

< script type="text/javascript" src="https://["YOUR FIREBASE PROJECT NAME"].firebaseapp.com/polyfills.14fc14f3e029a8cfd046.js"></script>

< script type="text/javascript" src="https://["YOUR FIREBASE PROJECT NAME"].firebaseapp.com/main.2eb2046276073df361f7.js"></script>
```

3rd step 
run the command `firebase deploy`

enjoy ! ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had ran to this issue and

If anybody had encounters the same after using firebase init command,

check your index.html file in your public folder (for react).

it might have been overridden by firebase.

in order to tell firebase not to override your existing index.html file,

type 'N' when firebase asks if you want to override the existing index.html file

Answer (score 3):

If someone is here because of a [image: Request timeout error]

it seems like some domains ending with web.app are blocked from ISP providers, for some countries, I used a private VPN and access my site until it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing what's in this screenshot, there's another `index.html` file generated by Firebase, and it points to this one instead of your own.  Here's how to fix:

1. Delete the Firebase-generated `index.html` and keep your own.
2. Re-deploy using `firebase deploy`

Answer (score 1):

For myself, the problem was I given an absolute path to my app location, `firebase init` seem's only take a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular v6 CLI projects are making it easier to have multiple apps with shared codebases. Hence the new folder within dist.

Quoting dotGitignore answer:

> I found that the ng build --prod will create a dist and an another
>   subfolder under this where the project location is.

Check how to fix it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360478/11652243

Answer (score 1):

Only solution is firebase deploy file is index.tml but we need build file so replace your

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Just replace your firebase.json file with this and you will se the magic

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me was using the second link that firebase provides instead of the first one:

USE: `your-project-id.firebaseapp.com` (instead of: `your-project-id.web.app`)

Comment: Why is the web.app version not working? Does it take long to propogate the DNS? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Wondering the same: `x.firebaseapp.com` works but not `x.web.app`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few instances where nothing is really needed. Move all your static files into the public folder you chose. use command

```
firebase deploy
```

and just clear the cache by hitting ctrl+f5.
that did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue when deploying a website in firebase.

Firebase usually creates two default domains, web.app and firebaseapp.com.
If one doesn't work out, use another.

This solved my problem. Try it!

Make sure that you uploading your files to firebase.

Else, use `firebase deploy --only hosting` to deploy to files from the public directory to firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for the usual deployment. https://alligator.io/angular/deploying-angular-app-to-firebase/

You have to check whether **index.html** inside the **dist** folder is regenerated by Firebase.

If so, all you need to do is just delete that html file which is modified by Firebase and create a new **index.html** file then enforcedly update the content with **index.html** which is actually created via `$ ng build --prod`. Now enter `$ firebase deploy --only hosting`.

So keep an eye of your index.html file contents and its location. if its location is not **dist** folder. you should give proper location accordingly for **public** field from **firebase.json** file.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. Follow below steps:

firebase init

```
*Are you ready to proceed?* Yes

Make a public folder and Copy your all files into it

*What do you want to use as your public directory?*(public) -->only press enter

*Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?(y/N)* N

*File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite?(y/N)* No
```

Thats it your app will host...

Answer (score 1):

@arslan's answer helped me here & worked for me, went from a blank webpage to being able to see my app.

My solution: I edited my firebase.json file and then npm run build and then re-ran my command firebase emulators:start. Changed the file from

```html
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to...

```html
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29796137)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself, What solved my issue:

1. ran build (npm run build)
2. add manually firebase.json and .firebasesrc files to root folder
3. make sure firebase.json hosting->public is set to "build
4. run firebase deploy

Comment: literally this solved my issue (build/web in my case), it was that simple

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I realised for some wierd reason, the firebase.json wasnt in my repo. I created it with config from the above examples, and then I did firebase init again, after it run it found my firebase.json and modified it, it worked

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and resolved with below steps:

**HACK Solution**

**Step:1** Go to your build folder and replace index.html with your index.html(public folder).

**Step:2** Run command: npm run build

**Step:3** Select **NO** => *File dist/{your-application-name}/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N)* **No**

**Step:4** Then go to the link and press Ctrl+f5. your app will be in front of you. :)

Answer (score 0):

after command firebase init, go to public or dist folder and select all files (not folders) except firebase related files and copy into dist or public folder. After this execute command firebase deploy and wait for a while. After finish go to mentioned url there you will find your working app.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran firebase init Firebase creates a file structure in your project folder and depending on the selections you made it created a /public folder (or another name if you specified) for your public files. Within that /public folder it also creates a index.html file containing the welcome message you are seeing. You need to take your app files (web pages, etc) and move them into that public folder and replace that index.html file along with them. After doing this run the command "firebase deploy" and it will update and you should see your app.

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying ensure your files are in the newly created directory e.g y or public folders

Answer (score 0):

in my case after building with `ng build` i told firebase the source directory is `dist`, but actually it was `dist/my-project`...

(there was a firebase index.html in `dist`. angular index.html was in `dist/my-project`...)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when this happen you need to logout `firebase logout` on your CLI,
then login again `firebase login`.

Then repeat all the procedures for hosting
And make sure you initialized Firebase `Firebase.initializeApp()` on your main method if you are using flutter.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

During initialization of the firebase directory you need to choose build as public directory.
The run

```js
1.npm run build
2.firbase deploy
```

If this doesn't work try clearing the cache of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

definitely clearing the cache worked with ctrl + f5 - i was pulling my hair out with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently after firebase updated it's site I never had any problems before but after I had this one the way you fix it is by doing all the steps normally and when you get to the firebase hosting set up complete page clear the cache by hitting 'CTRL + F5' which should fix the issue.

Alternatively you can add a new website and deploy your site to it instead by firebase deploy --only hosting:'sitename' and this should also work.

Answer (score -1):

Here I found an answer to the question

## Step1:

Initialize the firebase first.

```
$firebase init
```

## Step2:

Create a production build now.

```
$ng build --prod
```

## Step:3

It's time to deploy your app.

```
$firebase deploy
```