# Recieved this picture after deploying firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

i cannot fix this issue...
Terminal:
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\reactProjects\linkedin-clone> npm run build

> linkedin-clone@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

226 kB   build\static\js\main.0f7d0368.js
1.69 kB  build\static\css\main.e40a2faa.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

https://cra.link/deployment

[image]

Comment: This like means that the `public` key in your `firebase.json` file isn't pointing to the `build` folder that you are creating the app/HTML in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274084/firebase-hosting-not-showing-up-app for many more options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase hosting not showing up app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274084/firebase-hosting-not-showing-up-app)